# Property doesn't exist on type "object" error after checking if the property exists on the object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Issue:
I am trying to create a type guard, which should check if some values exist on a property of type unknown.

```
interface TestProps {
    count: number;
}

const getIsTestShown = (test: unknown): test is TestProps => {
    if (test && typeof test === "object") {
        if ("count" in test) {
            if (typeof test.count === "number") {  // ERROR: Property 'count' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

The above example is simplified, but represents exactly my problem. Typescript doesn't seem to understand that if  `"count" in test` is true, count should be accessible on test.
What am I missing?

Comment: `typeof test === object` is already a type guard. As a result you treat `test` as an object.

Comment: use `any` as the type of `test` in the argument list, not `unknown`

Comment: If you want to use `test: unknown` in the function parameter you have to narrow it down before access the `count` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it worked.
@NicoVignola could you maybe explain what you mean exactly? How would I be able in this example to use ```unknown``` for the parameter instead of using ```any```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
interface TestProps {
    count: number;
}

const getIsTestShown = (test: any): test is TestProps => {
    return typeof test?.count === "number" ?? false;
};

console.log(getIsTestShown({})) // false
console.log(getIsTestShown({ count: 1 })) // true
console.log(getIsTestShown({ count: "1" })); // false
console.log(getIsTestShown({ someOtherProp: "1" })); // false
```

If linters tell you not to use `any`, I would suggest to disable them for this particular function, since you're already checking the existence of the property and the type.

Edit: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-fZxVfsjxPZBW3YCAAHllGgM0CA-L8rxSKYgA) is a more detailed example of how you could use `unknown` and why it doesn't work just like `any`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem.
Could you explain me why I can't use ```unknown``` here?

Comment: To make it short, `unknown` is the type-safe counterpart to `any`. Unknown can be assigned to anything, but you can't assign anything to `unknown` nor perform any operations on it without first narrowing it down to a type. You can read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type)

Comment: @aronfischer I've edited the answer with a demo that should show you the difference